# XE5 iOS app - open PDF from local storage

Tags: ios, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5

I am developing an **iOS app** using **Delphi XE5**.

I have manage to download and store a PDF on the local device (using the Indy HTTP control), but I am unable to open the file for viewing directly from the local device storage.

```
//This points to the correct file which exists (in the emulator)
filename := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Test.pdf');
//points to  
//  /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/96674DE6-7997-48F9-9892-1383EBCE473B/Documents/Test.pdf
```

I have tried using the Apple.Utils class in the samples folder and using SharedApplication.OpenURL but this does not work (even if I convert the filename to a NSUrl).  Interestingly though, the canOpenURL returns true.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to simply "open" the PDF in a standard app to view it.  I have tried using the UIDocumentInteractionController but am not sure how to use it from the Delphi side.

Thanks,
Brendan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a TWebBrowser component to view the PDF works for me

```
filename := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Test.pdf');
WebBrowser1.Navigate('file:/' + filename);
```